# Rails - referencing other members of same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a family album application with Ruby on Rails. I have two main tables: "families" and "members." families has_many members.

I when I create a new "member" of a "family," I am attempting to track that new members relationship to the original member. My app allows you to create one original member, then all other members must be created from existing member's show pages. The idea is to not allow any new members to be added to the family without having a relationship established with an existing member. This will avoid floater members who are not related to anyone else.

I have a column called "parent_id." When a new member is created, you can add the current member's id (form is in member show view) as the parent_id for the new member. This links the records so they can be referenced later.

My question is fairly simple. In a member's show view, I want a table to display all members who have a parent_id == the current member's id. Pretty simple, but I can't get it to work. This is what I have now:

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <td>First</td>
            <td>Last</td>
            <td>Birthplace</td>
        </tr>
        <% @members.where("parent_id == @member.id").each do |p| %> 
            <tr>
                <td><%= p.first_name %></td>
                <td><%= p.last_name %></td>
                <td><%= p.birthplace %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %> 
    </table>
```

This is the error this code throws:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near ".": syntax error: SELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."family_id" = ? AND (parent_id == @member.id)
```

Here is the show action in my members controller:

```
def show
    @family = Family.find(params[:family_id])
    @member = Member.find(params[:id])
    @new = Member.new 
    @members = @family.members
end
```

Here is the schema for my two tables:

```
create_table "families", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "members", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "first_name"
t.string   "last_name"
t.string   "birthplace"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.integer  "family_id"
t.integer  "parent_id"
t.integer  "child_id"
t.integer  "sibling_id"
end
```

Comment: Your domain model is just not going to cut it. You need a series of join tables rather than just trying to jam everything into two tables. For example your model does not allow a member to have more than one sibling or belong to multiple families.  You need to read up on self-referential associations and go back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access to an `id` attribute within the `@members` object, which probably is an `ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy` from the `Member` model.

If you make an `@members.inspect` you'll see every element inside of it, as an array value has an `id` but not the object itself.

You could get each `member` id attribute if you iterate over every element and then in that way you're able to make the comparison `parent_id = member.id`, which could be safer if you do `'parent_id = ?', member.id` to avoid SQLi.

But I think you could check easier the members on `@members` just comparing its attributes:

```
<% @members.each do |member| %> 
  <% if member.parent_id == member.id  %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= member.first_name %></td>
      <td><%= member.last_name %></td>
      <td><%= member.birthplace %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```